# How to determine convergence of a power series?

Tags: real-analysis

What type of convergence  does the power series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}   \frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}$$
has in the interval $[-1,1]$ ?  ( that is, absolutely / uniformly convergent/ both/ neither)

Comment: use mathjax ${}{}$

Comment: This is **not** a power series

Answer (score 1):

It is not absolutely convergent:
$$\sum \frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}\geq\sum\frac{1}{n}=\infty,$$
since $\frac{x^2}{n^3}\geq 0$. On the other hand it is uniformely convergent:
Seperate in two sums:
$$\sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}=\sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2}{n^3}+\sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}$$
The second summand is convergent by Leibniz's test (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and independent of $x$. The other summand can be handled with the following argument:
$$\sum |(-1)\frac{x^2}{n^3}|\leq\sum \frac{1}{n^3}<\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Comparison Test to see that the series is not absolutely convergent. For testing convergence use the Leibniz Criterion.